# Creating an Integer set class using vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, set

I am trying to write the code for an integer class in C++ and the class object (the set) should be represented as a vector as the question says:

Create a class called IntegerSet. Each object of class IntegerSet can hold integers in the range 0 through the size of the set (or 100 if not specified).  Internally, a set is represented as a vector of ones and zeros.  The element at index i is set to zero if i is not included in the set, or 1 otherwise.

1. Provide two constructors for the class. The first constructor takes the size of the set, and initialize the vector accordingly. Originally, all the values are zeros. The default constructor initializes a vector of 100 elements.

I am confused as to how to initialize the class object as a vector and manipulate it because the method that I used either gives the following error: no match for ' operator [] 
or outputs nothing.

my code is the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class IntSet: public vector<int>
{
    public:
    //constructors: first one takes the size of a vector and initializes it accordingly,
    //second one initializes the vector to be of size 100
    IntSet(int size);
    IntSet();
    // intersection - that creates a third set that contains the common elements between two sets. 
    Intersection(IntSet& set2);
    //friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const )

};

IntSet::IntSet(int size)
{
    vector<int> set (size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
     set[i] =0;
}

IntSet::IntSet()
{
    vector<int> set (100);
}
/*
vector<int> IntSet::Intersection(IntSet& set2)
{
    vector<int> setOFcommon;
    for 

}
*/
int main()
{
    IntSet object(2);
    object[1]=9;
    object[2]=7;
    for(int x: object)
    cout<<x;
}
```

Comment: Your class should not inherit from `vector<int>` but contain a vector as a private member.

Comment: Both of your constructors create a local variable call "set" and initialize it. When the constructor returns, the local variable gets destroyed. The end result is that absolutely nothing of substance was accomplished. Have you studied, yet, the difference between local function variables and class members? And why are you inheriting from `std::vector`? There's nothing really inherently wrong with that, in the grand scheme of things, but it is unclear why you believe this will be a part of solution to the task that was described in the question.

Comment: what I understood from the question is that the set object should be a vector, thus initialized as a vector? can you explain more how I can approach it? and how what you mentioned about local function variables and class members relate to how I can solve the problem? thanks!

Comment: The best way for you to approach it is to spend some time reading your C++ book, practicing the sample tasks, and understanding the subject matter. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. This topic simply cannot be fully explained in sentence or two, on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I do read my C++ book daily and practice, I needed some help understanding how to approach this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how to do it

```
class IntSet
{
public:
    IntSet(int size);
private:
    vector<int> set;
};


IntSet::IntSet(int size) : set(size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        set[i] = 0;
}
```

You put the declaration of the `set` vector in the class, not in the constructor. In the constructor it's just a local variable and setting it has no effect on your class at all.

Also don't inherit from std::vector. Your class *has a* vector, it's not a *kind of* vector. Use inheritence for kind of relationships.

Comment: Well I fixed the error in the code, was there another reason for the down vote and delete vote?

Comment: At least zero-initializing the member is redundant. Also, with `using namespace std;` you could accidentally import `std::set`, too. But, those are minor details and I didn't downvote your answer.